# what does Map.Node<K,V> class in java?

Tags: java

I have seen a static nested classes **Node** and **Entry** in all **Java Collection Interfaces**,
i want to know that what is the use of these classes and how can i use Them directly?

Comment: You can't use them directly. They are internal implementation details, and are not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Map.Entry is a key and its value combined into one class. The allows you to iterate over Map.entrySet() without iterating over Keyset first.

for example : If mp is a Map

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mp.entrySet())
{
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

I don't see Node as a nested class in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>....  This Node class I found in calss Hashmap, Node is static Nested Class Hashmap, that is implementing Map.Entry

Comment: I have seen this Node class in JDK 8 Hashmap class

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html I don't see anywhere. Can you give the link.

Comment: u can check the below answer pic,

Comment: @Shashank : This class is used in internal implementation of the HashMap and you don't need to use that class

Comment: @Shashank : Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

**Result of javap tool on Hashmap$Node Class**

**Node class is also implementing the Entry interface** present in Map as well as **Hashmap has Static nested Entry Class too**.
May Be the Docs on oracle was not Updated with the changes the made in Jdk.

[image: "**Hashmap$Node Class**"]